# Changing Mode of Installer Not Working

Tags: command-line, software-installation, permissions

I am trying to run  `chmod +x /path/to/metasploit-latest-linux-x64-installer.run` in the terminal to mark the installer as executable, however I keep receiving an error:

```
cannot access ‘/path/to/metasploit-latest-linux-x64-installer.run’: No such file or directory
```

I am positive this file exist. I checked downloads in files, and it's 64-bit just like my installation of Ubuntu. I also had trouble doing this to another program. Is there a special software need to change the installer to executable? When I double click metasploit in downloads, it states I need to be a superuser.

FYI I have NO intentions of doing anything malicious. I just want to use metasploit to test a system on my network. I'm very new to Ubuntu.

Please help.

Comment: To prevent mistakes, instead of typing the whole path, drag it on to the terminal window.

Answer (score 1):

Aha! I see!

Try this out:

In terminal do the following:

1. Use `cd` to set the working directory to the location of the installer (i.e. `cd /home/GrammarGeek`)
2. Type `chmod a+x metasploit-latest-linux-x64-installer.ru`
3. Press tab
4. Press enter
5. Type `sudo ./metasploit-latest-linux-x64-installer.run`
6. Press enter
7. Profit!

(Please note `/path/to/metasploit-latest-linux-x64-installer.ru` is *not* a typo!)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I was away on a little mini vacation and back now. Unfortunately neither of these seemed to work. I do not understand why simple installations seem not to work. I just installed Ubuntu, is it possible I'm missing a special driver? Any other reasons this is not working?

Comment: This nay be a stupid question but, did you try replacing `/path/to/metasploit...` with the actual path to the installer?

Comment: Can you please clarify? The path to the installer? It's in my home directory, I see the metasploit file in there.

Comment: Ok so do `chmod +x /home/insertusernamehere/metasploit...`

Comment: To make it less confusing just look at the new instructions

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the drive you've extracted the `.run` installer to is an NTFS or FAT32 drive, or some other drive that doesn't support Unix-style permissions.

Instead, extract `metasploit-latest-linux-x64-installer.run` somewhere like your home folder where Unix-style permissions are supported and run:

```
chmod a+x $HOME/metasploit-latest-linux-x64-installer.run
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I was away on a little mini vacation and back now. Unfortunately neither of these seemed to work. I do not understand why simple installations seem not to work. I just installed Ubuntu, is it possible I'm missing a special driver? Any other reasons this is not working?

Answer (score 0):

`/Path/to` is the actual path where you have kept the downloaded Metasploit installer.

Same as in Windows `C:/users/downloads`....

Like for me it's:

```
chmod +x /home/dev/Downloads/metasploit-latest-linux-installer.run
```

Happy Linux :) !!

Answer (score 0):

Simply, open up your file explorer as superuser using command "sudo nautilus" (nautilus being the file explorer's name)
Then you can run that installer directly from there!